# Trouble trying to restart my Java program

Tags: java

After looking up numerous ways to restart a Java program within itself, a while loop seemed like the easiest option. Here's an example of a basic calculator program I'm trying this with:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class a {
public static void main(String args[]){
    boolean done = false;
    int oper;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("McMackins Calc v2.0 (Now with fewer crashes!)");
    while (!done)
    {
    System.out.println("What operation? (0 for quit, 1 for add, 2 for subtract, 3 for multiply, 4 for divide, 5 for divide with remainder, 6 for average, 7 for account interest):");
    while (!input.hasNextInt()){
        System.out.println("Enter a valid integer.");
        input.next();
    }
    oper = input.nextInt();
    switch (oper){
    case 0:
        done = true;
        break;
    case 1:
        add addObject = new add();
        addObject.getSum();
        break;
    case 2:
        sub subObject = new sub();
        subObject.getDifference();
        break;
    case 3:
        times multObject = new times();
        multObject.getProduct();
        break;
    case 4:
        divide divObject = new divide();
        divObject.getQuotient();
        break;
    case 5:
        remain remObject = new remain();
        remObject.getRemainder();
        break;
    case 6:
        avg avgObject = new avg();
        avgObject.getAvg();
        break;
    case 7:
        interest intObject = new interest();
        intObject.getInterest();
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Invalid entry.");
        break;
    }
    }
    input.close();
}
}
```

However, this seems to throw out a NoSuchElementException at the end of the first time through the loop, and crashes the program. The function of this class is to take the initial input from the user to determine which class to use, which will determine which mathematical operation to perform. Everything works fine without the `while (!done)` loop.

Example usage:

```
McMackins Calc v2.0 (Now with fewer crashes!)
What operation? (0 for quit, 1 for add, 2 for subtract, 3 for multiply, 4 for divide, 5 for divide with remainder, 6 for average, 7 for account interest):
1
How many addends?
1
Enter your numbers now.
1
You have entered 1 addend.
The sum is: 1.0
What operation? (0 for quit, 1 for add, 2 for subtract, 3 for multiply, 4 for divide, 5 for divide with remainder, 6 for average, 7 for account interest):
Enter a valid integer.
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at a.main(a.java:13)
```

I've also tried just having the other classes refer back to this one, but since main is a static method, I cannot access it the way I intended.

Note that I'm a bit of a beginner at Java, which is why my program is pretty simple, so try to keep it simple if it can be, or post code and then in DETAIL explain what it means so I can not only fix this problem, but future ones as well.

Thank you!

EDIT:

The code is formatted better within my editor. The braces came out in odd positions when I posted it here.

Since apparently `a` is written correctly, this is my `add` class. Hopefully this will clear something up.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class add {
public void getSum(){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    double total, addend;
    int entries, count;
    total = 0;
    count = 0;
    System.out.println("How many addends?");
    while (!input.hasNextInt()){
        System.out.println("Enter a valid integer.");
        input.next();
    }
    entries = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter your numbers now.");

    while (count < entries){
        while (!input.hasNextDouble()){
            System.out.println("Enter a valid number.");
            input.next();
        }
        addend = input.nextDouble();
        total = total + addend;
        count++;
        if (count == 1){
            System.out.println("You have entered " + count + " addend.");
        }else if (count > entries){
            System.out.println("You have entered too many addends! Contact program developer.");
        }else{
            System.out.println("You have entered " + count + " addends.");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The sum is: " + total);
    input.close();
}
}
```

Comment: how about posting the exception?

Comment: could you format the code better.  The indentation is wrong and it is not clear which 'while' ends where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    boolean done = false;
    int oper;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("McMackins Calc v2.0 (Now with fewer crashes!)");

    while (!done) {
        System.out.println("What operation? (0 for quit, 1 for add, 2 for subtract, 3 for multiply, 4 for divide, 5 for divide with remainder, 6 for average, 7 for account interest):");
        while (!input.hasNextInt()){
            System.out.println("Enter a valid integer.");
            input.next();
        }
        oper = input.nextInt();
        switch (oper){
        case 0:
            done = true;
            break;
        case 1:
            System.out.println("1");
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("2");
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("3");
            break;
        case 4:
            System.out.println("4");
            break;
        case 5:
            System.out.println("5");
            break;
        case 6:
            System.out.println("6");
            break;
        case 7:
            System.out.println("7");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid entry.");
            break;
        }
    }
    input.close();
}
```

This seemed to work for me so perhaps the error is something to do with your own classes (add, divide) etc.

Also, it's best to keep with convention when creating your own classes by capitalizing the first letter e.g. "add" should be "Add".

You could probably make this a little bit easier to read by building a general "Operations" class which holds an add method, a subtract method etc.

**EDIT:**
try this for your add method:

```
public static int add() {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int counter = 0;

        System.out.println("How many numbers to add?");
        int numCount = s.nextInt();

        for(int i = 0; i < numCount; i++) {
            System.out.println("enter number");
            counter += s.nextInt();
        }

        return counter;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing. Making a general operations class doesn't sound like a bad idea. The reason it ended up like that is because I just wanted to practice working with many classes so that I'd get used to it. I could post my `add` class if it might help with figuring out where I've screwed up.

Comment: No problem! Yeah, post your add class and I'll take a look. It could well be that it's expecting an integer ahead of time or the other way round.

Comment: Add class is now in the main post.

Comment: Added my own implementation for the add method above. Similar to yours but without all the confusing variables and while loops

Comment: Efficient as that is, it assumes the user only wants to add integers. Also, the numerous while loops can sometimes be overlooked. They check to make sure the input is valid and to tell them if they've typed anything incorrectly. Without them, the program simply crashes if you give a string as input rather than a number.

Comment: Well obviously there has to be some validation but I wasn't about to sit here and type that bit for you. I was merely giving you foundation to work on top of ;)

Comment: Okay, then. I'll work on that later today. Also, is this a fix for my problem or just a more efficient way to write my `getSum` method? I also see that this method is static. Can that even be accessed by `a` with the way that's set up?

Comment: This is a fix and an improvement. A fix in a way where it works (from what I've tested) and an improvement where there's only one loop and it's easier to understand. (You can add validation within the loop)

It's static because I implemented this method within a static class so instead of having to create an object of the class (Operations operations = new Operations; operations.add;), I could just write "Operations.add();"

Answer (score 1):

Use `bufferedreader` and `inputstream` instead of Scanner class. This class creates a lot of bugs and errors, since sometimes it takes more arguments, that you expect it to take.
Also:

```
while (!input.hasNextInt()){
    System.out.println("Enter a valid integer.");
    input.next();
}
```

Your using `hasNextInt` method wrong, instead of it try to make simple while loop with Boolean and `input.next()` should be replaced with `input.nextLine()`.

Another thing, you should check,if user typed integer instead of string or something in the while loop and it range. If everything is okay, you should change Boolean value to true and make him go out of the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

For future users who are wondering how to fix this issue, through some reprogramming, I discovered that my problem was closing the `input` variable BEFORE the end of the loop. By having the program restart indefinitely and only close `input` when done, this program works fine.

Thanks to Benjamin's response, I am currently in the process of cleaning up and shortening my code by way of `for` loops.